# How to get the name of the product finally added to cart

Tags: magento-1.6

I want the name of the product which was finally added to the cart.

```
$productID=Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastAddedProductId(true);
$_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productID);
$session= Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
foreach($session->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item)
{
    $productID = $item->getProductId();
    $productSku = $item->getSku();
    $productName = $item->getName();
    $productQty = $item->getQty();    

}
```

I found some code like this, but it does not works as the way in which I need. This returns the set of all products in the cart.

If a product already in cart is added to cart again, this code does not give the correct output.

Answer (score 1):

hi you can get  from quote item ids and just fetch current quote latest item.

Use `getAllItems` function instead  `getAllVisibleItems`

```
$session= Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$latestID=0;
$latestProductId=0;
$latestProductName='';



   foreach($session->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item)
    {
    if($latestID<$item->getId() ){
    $latestID=$item->getId();
    $latestProductId=$item->getProductId();
   $latestProductName= $item->getName()   
    }
        $productID = $item->getProductId();

        $productSku = $item->getSku();
        $productName = $item->getName();
        $productQty = $item->getQty();    

    }
```

**echo latestProductId;** and can get last added product in cart  by  `$latestProductName`

Get all items of current quote items ids and then get maximum id item which is your latest product which is added in cart

Answer (score 1):

You can use observer called `<checkout_cart_product_add_after>` here Neo is my pacakge name and Catalog is my module name

config.xml

```
<events>
    <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
        <observers>
            <get_last_added_pro>
                <type>singleton</type> 
                <class>Neo_Catalog_Model_Observer</class> 
                <method>getlastaddedpro</method> 
            </get_last_added_pro>
        </observers>
    </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
</events>
```

observer.php

```
public function getlastaddedpro($observer){
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        Mage::log($product->getName(),null,'product.log'); // with $product->getData(); u will get all the details of last added product
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just use array_reverse function of PHP. That will reverse your array and give the last added product first. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php