# Is there any way to get the last added product to cart?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, event-observer, products, ajax

I would like to show a popup that gives an overview of the product that the customer has just bought it, so I need to display a popup with item name and its other attributes like color, image, name etc when we add this product in cart.
this popup I need to be display when clicking add to cart button on product page.

I use an observer `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` I try everything but I can't get the last add to cart product name of the associated product. I use `->getLastAddedProductId(true)` seems to not working, I try to use this code but it seems to not working:

```
   $main_product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $associated_product = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
    $productSku = $main_product ->getSku();  //for configurable product
    $productQty = $main_product ->getQty();  //for configurable product
    if($product->getTypeID() == 'configurable'){
      //to get the id or sku of associated product use the following.
      $simple_product_id = $quoteitem->getProduct()->getId();
      $simple_product_sku = $quoteitem->getProduct()->getSku();
    }
```

I use the code below and this is working but only thing is this code get me the last product and I need to get the current:

```
  $items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
    $max = 0;
    $lastItem = null;
    foreach ($items as $item){
        if ($item->getId() > $max) {
            $max = $item->getId();
            $lastItem = $item;
        }
    }
    if ($lastItem){
        $_product = $lastItem->getProduct();
        $xproductsku = $_product->getSku();
       $xproductname = $_product->getName();               
       $xproductqty = $_product->getQty();  
       $xproductprice = $_product->getPrice();   
       $xproducturl = $_product->getUrl();
    }
```

here is another post where you can view my entire code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28642855/how-can-i-add-ajax-notice-when-the-product-was-successfully-added-to-cart

you have an idea how can I make this to work?

### My entire Observer.php file:

```
    public function addToCartEvent($observer)
    {
        $request = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest();
        if (!$request->getParam('in_cart') && !$request->getParam('is_checkout'))
        {
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setNoCartRedirect(true);
            $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
            $grandTotal = $quote->getGrandTotal();
            $subTotal = $quote->getSubtotal();
            $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
            $shippingTaxamount = Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData('tax_amount');

            // get coupon discounted value            

            $totals = $quote->getTotals(); //Total object
            if (isset($totals['discount']) && $totals['discount']->getValue())
            {
                $discount = Mage::helper('core')->currency($totals['discount']->getValue()); //Discount value if applied
            }
            else
            {
                $discount = '';
            }

            //get discount value end     

            $xitems = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
            $max = 0;
            $lastItem = null;
            foreach ($xitems as $xitem)
            {
                if ($xitem->getId() > $max)
                {
                    $max = $xitem->getId();
                    $lastItem = $xitem;
                    $attributeSetModel1 = Mage::getModel("eav/entity_attribute_set")->load($lastItem->getProduct()->getAttributeSetId());
                    $attributeSetName1 = $attributeSetModel1->getAttributeSetName();
                    $parentIds1 = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($lastItem->getProduct()->getId());
                    if ($lastItem->getProduct()->getTypeId() == 'simple' && empty($parentIds1) && $attributeSetName1 == 'Default')
                    {
                        $child = $lastItem;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $child = $lastItem->getOptionByCode('simple_product')->getProduct();
                    }
                }
            }





            $html = '';
            $productser = '';
            foreach ($session->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item)
            {
                if ($lastItem)
                {
                    $xproduct = $lastItem->getProduct();
                    $xproductsku = $xproduct->getSku();
                    $xproductname = $xproduct->getName();
                    $xproductqty = $xproduct->getQty();
                    $xproductprice = $xproduct->getPrice();
                    $xproducturl = $xproduct->getUrl();
                }






                $productOptions = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());
                if ($productOptions)
                {
                    if (isset($productOptions['options']))
                    {
                        foreach ($productOptions['options'] as $_option)
                        {
                            $productser = $_option['option_id'] . ',' . $_option['option_value'];
                        }
                    }
                    $superAttrString = '';
                    if (isset($productOptions['info_buyRequest']['super_attribute']))
                    {
                        foreach ($productOptions['info_buyRequest']['super_attribute'] as $key => $_superAttr)
                        {
                            $attr = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($key);
                            $label = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($_superAttr);
                            $superAttrString .= '<dt> ' . $attr->getAttributeCode() . ' </dt> <dd> ' . $label . ' </dd>';
                        }
                    }
                    if ($superAttrString):
                        $superAttrString . '&qty=1';
                    endif;
                }








                $productid = $item->getId();
                $html .='<li id="li-' . $productid . '">';
                $product_id = $item->getProduct()->getId();
                $productsku = $item->getSku();
                $productname = $item->getName();
                $productqty = $item->getQty();
                $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
                $url = Mage::getUrl(
                                'checkout/cart/deleteqty', array(
                            'id' => $productid,
                            Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED => Mage::helper('core/url')->getEncodedUrl()
                                )
                );










                $count = $quote->getItemsCount();
                $html .='<div class="item-thumbnail">';
                if ($item->hasProductUrl()):
                    $html .='<a href="' . $item->getUrl() . '" title="' . $item->getName() . '" class="product-image"><img src="' . Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($item->getProduct(), 'thumbnail') . '" width="50" height="50" alt="' . $this->escapeHtml($item->getName()) . '" /></a>';
                else:
                    $html .='<span><img src="' . Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($item->getProduct(), 'thumbnail') . '" width="50" height="50" alt="' . $item->getName() . '" /></span>';
                endif;
                $html .='</div>';
                $html .='<div class="mini-basket-content-wrapper">
                        <div class="mini-cart-name">
                        <a class="item-name" href="' . $item->getUrl() . '">' . $productname . '</a> <span class="item-price"><span class="price">$' . $item->getPrice() . '</span></span>
                <div class="truncated_full_value">
        <dl class="item-options">
            <dd class="truncated">
                <div class="truncated_full_value">
                    <dl class="item-options">
                        ' . $superAttrString . '
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </dd>
        </dl>
     </div>

        <div class="product-cart-sku">SKU: # ' . $productsku . '</div>
            <div class="product-qty">Quantity: ' . $productqty . '</div>
                    </div>  
                   </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>';
                $html .='</li>';



$collection = Mage::getSingelton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection(); 
$collection->getSelect()->order('created_at DESC'); 
$latestItems = $collection->getFirstItem();
$productse = $latestItems->getProduct();

$productnamese=$productse->getName();

                $xhtml .='<div class="product-qty">Quantity: ' . $productnamese . '</div>';


            }








            $_response = Mage::getModel('ajaxminicart/response')
                    ->setProductName($observer->getProduct()->getName())
                    ->setCarttotal($grandTotal)
                    ->setCartsubtotal($subTotal)
                    ->setCartcount($count)
                    ->setDiscount($discount)
                    ->setShippingtaxamount($shippingTaxamount)
                    ->setCartitem($html)
                     ->setMessage($xhtml);

            //append updated blocks

            $_response->addUpdatedBlocks($_response);
            $_response->send();
        }

        if ($request->getParam('is_checkout'))
        {
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setNoCartRedirect(true);
            $_response = Mage::getModel('ajaxminicart/response')
                    ->setProductName($observer->getProduct()->getName())
                    ->setMessage(Mage::helper('checkout')->__('%s was added into cart.', $observer->getProduct()->getName()));
            $_response->send();
        }
    }

    public function updateItemEvent($observer)
    {
        $request = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest();
        if (!$request->getParam('in_cart') && !$request->getParam('is_checkout'))
        {
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setNoCartRedirect(true);
            $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
            $grandTotal = $quote->getGrandTotal();
            $subTotal = $quote->getSubtotal();
            $shippingTaxamount = Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData('tax_amount');

            // get coupon discounted value            

            $totals = $quote->getTotals(); //Total object
            if (isset($totals['discount']) && $totals['discount']->getValue())
            {
                $discount = Mage::helper('core')->currency($totals['discount']->getValue()); //Discount value if applied
            }
            else
            {
                $discount = '';
            }

            //get discount value end                

            $_response = Mage::getModel('ajaxminicart/response')
                    ->setCarttotal($grandTotal)
                    ->setCartsubtotal($subTotal)
                    ->setShippingtaxamount($shippingTaxamount)
                    ->setDiscount($discount)
                    ->setMessage(Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Item was updated'));

            //append updated blocks
            $_response->addUpdatedBlocks($_response);
            $_response->send();
        }

        if ($request->getParam('is_checkout'))
        {
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setNoCartRedirect(true);
            $_response = Mage::getModel('ajaxminicart/response')
                    ->setMessage(Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Item was updated'));
            $_response->send();
        }
    }

    public function getConfigurableOptions($observer)
    {

        $is_ajax = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParam('ajax');
        if ($is_ajax)
        {
            $_response = Mage::getModel('ajaxminicart/response');
            $_response = Mage::getModel('ajaxminicart/response');
            $product = Mage::registry('current_product');
            if (!$product->isConfigurable() && !$product->getTypeId() == 'bundle')
            {
                return false;
                exit;
            }

            //append configurable options block

            $_response->addConfigurableOptionsBlock($_response);
            $_response->send();
        }

        return;
    }

    public function getGroupProductOptions()
    {

        $id = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParam('product');
        $options = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParam('super_group');
        if ($id)
        {

            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
            if ($product->getData())
            {
                if ($product->getTypeId() == 'grouped' && !$options)
                {
                    $_response = Mage::getModel('ajaxminicart/response');
                    Mage::register('product', $product);
                    Mage::register('current_product', $product);
                    //add group product's items block
                    $_response->addGroupProductItemsBlock($_response);
                    $_response->send();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastAddedProductId(true);
```

... is actually clearing the session variable after it is read. Magento uses magic methods extensively. In this case you are using the `__call()` magic method which in turn uses the `getData()` method. In `Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien` you will see that they override the default behaviour of `getData()` to expect the second parameter to be a boolean (The first parameter to `getData()` is the key name for the value you are looking for). That boolean is a flag telling the session to clear the variable after reading.

You could always listen for the `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event and add the item to your own variable in the session. That event is actually fired on the line before `setLastAddedProductId()` is called.

Refered links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208650/get-id-of-the-last-product-added-to-the-cart-in-magento
- http://www.codexpedia.com/magento/magento-get-the-last-added-product-id-and-cart-items/

**Edit 1:**

You're almost there - try this code:

```
$collection = Mage::getSingelton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();

$collection->getSelect()->order('created_at DESC');

$latestItem = $collection->getFirstItem();
```

Note that when you get the latest quote item, you're not actually obtaining the product. To get the actual product, you would need to add this line:

```
$product = $latestItem->getProduct();
```

**Edit 2:**

Use this below code

Code to get the the full product information (where 3 is the configurable product Id)

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(3); 

$childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                ->getUsedProducts(null,$product);

foreach($childProducts as $child) {
    print_r($child->getName());  // You can use any of the magic get functions on this object to get the value
}
```

**Edit 3:**

You can also get by sku

```
$associated_products = $_product->loadByAttribute('sku', $_product->getSku())->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts();

foreach ($associated_products as $assoc) 
{
    $assocProduct   = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($assoc->getId());
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nanda yes I know that but I don;t know how to make this with my code, I edited my post can you see my code below in stackoverfloe link

Comment: Can you try my new edit code ?

Comment: yes thank you but there is an error I don;t know why, I try to get the name like this $productnamese=$product->getName(); ohh and I forget, I need the associated simple product name in configurable

Comment: Are you getting other than names ? Please post your code

Comment: Whether its working now ?

Comment: I will add here my entire php file code, is ok?

Comment: please take a look I edit my post and I add the entire php file, thank you so much, if you can solve this you can save my life :)

Comment: you need to get all the simple products details of the configurable products ? Right ?

Comment: yes nanda, i need to get the current simple product details tha was added in the cart

Comment: Please check my edit 2 and 3

Comment: can you add this directly in my observer.php file? i need to add simple products data in this  ->setMessage($xhtml);

Comment: and I don't know what is my product Id, I can't know this, the id must be the id of the current added to cart product

Comment: Please post the results of $latestItem->getProduct()

Comment: This is the results: "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://nlyclothing.com/index.php/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL25seWNsb3RoaW5nLmNvbS9pbmRleC5waHAvc2hvcC9jbG90aGluZy9kZW5pbS9zaG9lcy1jb25maWd1cmFibGUuaHRtbA,,/product/21/form_key/fn3XNy1Sufq8SkDW/"

Comment: I add the code at the bottom of your answer please edit your code there, is much simple for both of us. Thank you

Comment: Have you got the Id ?

Comment: no how can i get the ID?

Comment: i use this but is not working:$associated_products = $_product->loadByAttribute('sku', $_product->getSku())->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts();

foreach ($associated_products as $assoc) {

$assocProduct   = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($assoc->getId());

}

Comment: can you take a look here? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42242/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-product-finally-added-to-cart I think this must be our solution but is not work

Comment: are you there? you see this last link?

Comment: Yeah. I've seen that. Please post what u have tried so far.

Comment: I try everything :) I don't know for where I start now so look if I use this code and the sku is working, it display me the current associated product:

$main_product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
$associated_product = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
$productxSku = $main_product ->getSku();
$productxQty = $main_product ->getQty();

Comment: only sku is working, how can I get the name image ...?

Comment: Sorry can't understand

Comment: $productxSku = $main_product ->getSku(); is the only thing that is working, I need to know how can I getName, Image, Description ....

Comment: Use $main_product->getData(); to show all

Comment: and how can I get name for example? with this code? $main_product->getData();

Comment: $main_product ->getData('name'); i use the code like this but is return me the configurable name, not the associated simple product name

Comment: Use this code $associated_products = $_product->loadByAttribute('sku', $main_product ->getSku())->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts();

foreach ($associated_products as $assoc) {

$assocProduct   = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($assoc->getId());
}

Comment: Above i have used your main product sku
$_product->loadByAttribute('sku', $main_product ->getSku())->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts();

Comment: yes but this is not working what is $_product? i am in the backend of the extension

Comment: $_product is $main_product

Comment: look this is the extension that i use for ajax MiniCart, if you want please install this on your local, add the code and give me the code here please? we waste so much time for this :) http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ajax-mini-cart-ajax-cart.html

Comment: so all I want is to add a new popup with the current product that was bought it when a product is added to cart

Comment: is okay for you? this is the file about we talk app\code\community\Datta\Ajaxminicart\Model\Observer.php

Comment: You can try this free extension http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webinse-ajax-cart.html

Comment: ok :) thank you for your efforts but this is not the answer that I need

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$itemsCollection = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
if($itemsCollection) {
    $lastQuoteItem = array_pop($quoteItemsCollection);
    $lastAddedProduct = $lastQuoteItem->getProduct();
}
```

Comment: This might give you weird results with bundles and configurable products, because you don't filter out child items.

Answer (score 0):

Below Code is used for getting cart items

```
$cart = new Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart();

$cart->init();

foreach ($cart->getItems() as $item) {

   // we can wrap our request in this IF statement

   if (!$item->getParentItemId()) {

   }
}
```

It looks like their sort by adding, so just get the last looped item.

Comment: Thank you but I am able to get all products, I need to get the current one, all I want to do is to replace this ->setMessage(Mage::helper('checkout')->__('%s was added into cart.', $observer->getProduct()->getName())); with all product details: image, Name, description